# Generate Package.swift from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, travis-ci, swift-package-manager

I've added some dependencies to my project using Xcode and I need to generate a `Package.swift` file for `Travis-CI`.

Is there a solution other than manually add all my dependencies to this file?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the problem the wrong way.

Package.swift should be the basis of your framework, not the Xcode project. You can generate an Xcode project from a Package file, but you cannot generate a package file from an Xcode project.

The main reason behind this is that Xcode projects support many things that Swift Package Manager (and hence Package.swift files) do not support - such as mixed language targets or signing & capabilities.

So if your project setup is fully supported by SPM, you should simply throw away the Xcode project and rely on the Package.swift file completely, otherwise you'll need to keep using Xcode projects and shouldn't use SPM until it supports your requirements.

Comment: Oh ... The fact is that I'm moving a project from Carthage to SwiftPM and I've already installed my package from Xcode